# Determining if any duplicate rows in two matrices in MatLab

Tags: matlab, duplicates

**Introduction to problem:**

I'm modelling a system where i have a matrix X=([0,0,0];[0,1,0],...) where each row represent a point in 3D-space. I then choose a random row, r,  and take all following rows and rotate around the point represented by r, and make a new matrix from these rows, X_rot. I now want to check whether any of the rows from X_rot is equal two any of the rows of X (i.e. two vertices on top of each other), and if that is the case refuse the rotation and try again.

**Actual question:**

Until now i have used the following code:

```
X_sim=[X;X_rot];
if numel(unique(X_sim,'rows'))==numel(X_sim);
    X(r+1:N+1,:,:)=X_rot;
end
```

Which works, but it takes up over 50% of my running time and i were considering if anybody in here knew a more efficient way to do it, since i don't need all the information that i get from `unique`.

P.S. if it matters then i typically have between 100 and 1000 rows in `X`.

Best regards,
Morten

**Additional:**
My `x`-matrix contains N+1 rows and i have 12 different rotational operations that i can apply to the sub-matrix x_rot:

```
step=ceil(rand()*N);
r=ceil(rand()*12);
x_rot=x(step+1:N+1,:);
x_rot=bsxfun(@minus,x_rot,x(step,:));
x_rot=x_rot*Rot(:,:,:,r);
x_rot=bsxfun(@plus,x_rot,x(step,:));
```

Comment: Share the code where you calculate `X_rot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible approaches (I don't know if they are faster than using `unique`):

1. Use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html):

   ```
   d = pdist2(X, X_rot, 'hamming'); %// 0 if rows are equal, 1 if different.
   %// Any distance function will do, so try those available and choose fastest
   result = any(d(:)==0);
   ```
2. Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

   ```
   d = squeeze(any(bsxfun(@ne, X, permute(X_rot, [3 2 1])), 2));
   result = any(d(:)==0);
   ```

`result` is `1` if there is a row of `X` equal to some row of `X_rot`, and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Your suggestion with `bsxfun` seems to run at 70% of the time of `unique` in my case, so a significant improvement. Thanks a lot, you've saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

How about `ismember(X_rot, X, 'rows')`?

Comment: What do you mean by "same-index rows"? Like, it compares `X_rot(1,:)` against `X(1,:)`, `X_rot(2,:)` against `X(2,:)`, and so on? In that case, no – functionally, `ismember(A, B)` will take each row in `A` and search through all rows in `B` until it finds a match or exhausts all the rows in `B` without finding a match.

Comment: I need it to tell me if any element of `x_rot` is contained in `x` if i understand `ismember` right it only returns true if all the elements of `x_rot` is contained in `x`?

Comment: No. `ismember` will return a vector of logicals and indexes indicating for _each element or row_ of `x_rot` whether it is contained in `x`, and if so where. E.g. if `x_rot` is 125 rows long, then `[tf,ix] = ismember(x_rot, x, 'rows')` will return a 125-long logical for `tf` and a 125-long double of indexes for `ix`, and `x_rot(tf,:)` will give you all the rows which were duplicates of rows in `x`.

Comment: No, sorry didn't read the documentation properly. But in my implementation it is slow compared to the unique-approach.

But thank you for the feedback

Comment: @AndrewJanke You're right. I meant that, but now I see I was wrong. Sorry about the confusion. +1 for this approach